# d3.js dendrogram with leaves rendered as key-value pairs

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, hierarchical-data, dendrogram

Working with d3.js and I have hierarchical data and working with this example [d3 dendrogram](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063570) which nearly meets my needs, but instead of a text string as the leaf, I need to display a table. The data follows this pattern:

```
{"name": "root",
 "children": [
  {"name": "dtable",
   "children": [
    {"label": "la01", "tag":"section", "title":"Section One"}
    {"label": "la02", "tag":"section", "title":"Section Two"}
    {"label": "la0201", "tag":"subsection", "title":"Subsection Two:One"}
    ]
  }
}
```

I'd like the leaf to be rendered something like this:

```
----------------------------------------------
| label    | tag        | title              |
----------------------------------------------
| la01     | section    | Section One        |
| la02     | section    | Section Two        |
| la0201   | subsection | Subsection Two:One |
----------------------------------------------
```

The d3 example has this snippet which displays the leaf as a text-string. I'm at a loss on how to reengineer or replace the code to show a table instead:

```
nodeEnter.append("svg:text")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
  .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rendering something as large as a table might be difficult to achieve space-wise. The easiest way would be to append a [`foreignObject` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject) instead of the `text` element and then create a HTML `table` that contains the data you need to show.

See [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1424037) for an example of how to use `foreignObject`. You may also find [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) helpful for creating the actual table.